# image gallery using filesystem with description stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I'm trying to create a gallery for a client and want it to be easy to update for them.
I have the uploading down and working, having them upload an image and it stores in a folder named "img". Also when they upload an image they must enter a title and description of the image which I am currently storing in a table in the database.

Database is organised like this:

```
ID(AI)  |  Name  |  Description  |  Image  |  Date(timestamp)
```

with the Image field being the image name and extention, ex:

```
$image = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

and saved in the DB.

If that part is unnecessary or redundant I can remove it I just thought it would make things easier?

So now I'm trying to retrieve the images from the folder and display the appropriate name and description for each image. What would be the best way to do this??

Right now I have all the pictures being displayed using:

```
$dirname = "img/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" width="200" height="200"/><br />';
}
```

I've been searching Google and here and can't seem to find anything.. Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Why look for images in your directory if you store their info in DB? Just fetch all records from DB and iterate over them.

Comment: I suggest you to do the other way. Please remember that i do not know your code however it's best to take the name for the file from the db, even the path and read the file (only when necessary). This way if some hacker enter into the ftp and upload strange things it will help you to not put yourself KO too much.

Comment: Okay so you guys saying just add a loop for the whole table and when it comes to image put something like <img src='img/".$res['image']."' /> or along those lines??

Comment: Yup, i will suggest that noelllll, it's safer and make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is to assign your OWN filename to the actual on-disk files, e.g. use the record ID from the database, so you end up with `1.jpg`, `2,jpg`, etc.... This prevents MANY problems, like filename collisions, malicious filenames that include pathing information, filenames with "naughty" words, etc... Anyone bypassing your gallery system to directly access the image files would only see "1.jpg", and not the "really_nasty_swear_words.jpg" that it was uploaded with originally.

On the flip side, when it comes time to actually serve up those images, you can always use a simple PHP script as the intermediary, and then include the original filename there. e.g.

```
http://example.com/image.php?id=42

<?php
if (user_can_access_image($_GET['id'])) {
    $filename = get_name_from_db($_GET['id']);
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    readfile("/path/to/images/$_GET[id].jpg");
} else {
    readfile("/path/to/unauthorized.jpg");
}
```

Note that this code is not totally secure, and is just as used as an example.

Comment: That does sound muchh better, but how do i change the name of the image being saved in the first place? I'm sorry but I'm not too advanced in PHP so this is getting a bit confusing..lol Also Goikiu thank you, your answer has worked! Will be using that for the time being at least, I'm not too worried about security as it's a site for one person and probably won't be getting much traffic anyways

Comment: multi-stage process. a) validate the update (check if it succeeded, matches criteria, etc...) b) create placeholder record in DB so that an ID number gets assigned. c) move_uploaded_file() using that new ID as the destination filename. d) if a->c succeed, update the placeholder DB record with any other necessary information.